# Compiler options for emitting constant-time object code

Tags: security, gcc, compilation, clang, compiler-optimization

I'm looking for `gcc` and `clang` compiler options that effectively tell the compiler to emit constant-time object code. Ideally there'd be a compiler option equivalent to `-Os` that instead of optimizing for size, optimizes for constant-timeness of the emitted code. Current compilers to my knowledge do not provide such an option, so what I'm asking for really is a set of compiler options that would have a similar effect.

Comment: I think you have answered your own question: gcc and clang do not support this.  It would necessarily limit you to a subset of C with no loops except maybe obviously constant ones.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68327985/require-compiler-to-emit-branchless-constant-time-code, which is unanswered but has comments explaining that it's not feasible.

Comment: Well I was thinking of options such as `-ftree-loop-if-convert` (`gcc`) that can have such an effect on the emitted code. Unlike the linked question, I'm not looking for a perfect solution.